# How to set custom title for not found pages in Remix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I'm setting up my 404 page on a Remix app but I'm struggling on how to set the `<title>` meta tag for such pages.

In my `root.tsx` I have a `MetaFunction` and a `CatchBoundary`:

```
export const meta: MetaFunction = () => {
  return {
    charset: "utf-8",
    title: "New Remix App",
    viewport: "width=device-width,initial-scale=1",
  };
};

export function CatchBoundary() {
  const caught = useCatch();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <h1>Caught</h1>
          <p>Status: {caught.status}</p>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(caught.data, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I tried using the `data` parameter of the `MetaFunction` but it's not guaranteed that not having `data` means that it is a not found response catch.

I went through several pages looking for an answer, including:

- https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/not-found
- https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#catchboundary

This is the repository:

- https://github.com/oncet/blog

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tag `<title>` directly in your `return` of the `CatchBoundary()` like this:

```
export function CatchBoundary() {
  const caught = useCatch();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Oops! Something went wrong!</title>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <h1>Caught</h1>
          <p>Status: {caught.status}</p>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(caught.data, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I set my MetaFunction like this:

```
export const meta: MetaFunction = () => ({
    charset: "utf-8",
    title: "Test title",
    viewport: "width=device-width,initial-scale=1",
});
```

It should give something like this:

- [Normal routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lHqn.png)
- [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q7Vf.png)

Comment: Problem with this approach is that the `<Meta />` component will also render a `<title>` tag with a different value.

Comment: Seems like I can't reproduce your problem. The `<title>` tag in `CatchBoundary()` works fine for me with `<Meta />` component. Please check my edited answer for more information.

Comment: If you inspect the DOM in Google Chrome, don't you see 2 `<title>` tags? One with "Oops! Something went wrong!" and the other one with "Test title"

Comment: I don't believe there is any other ways to work around with this since this is the intended way to [handle 404 error](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/not-found#root-catch-boundary) in Remix.run. The `<title>`  will get rendered first, so the title in the `<Meta />` will have no effects.